# Regex search with Gulp and log results to console?

Tags: gulp

I need to find a certain group mixins in my SASS which will always have this format:

```
@include sprite-something;
```

I can find them with this regex:

```
/@include sprite-*/g
```

Can I use gulp to find this pattern and log to the console which ones it finds?

So if this was my SASS

```
.header {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.something {
  @include sprite-one;
}
.something-else {
  @include sprite-two;
}
```

Then the console would log `@include sprite-one` and `@include sprite-two`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your regex is wrong. It would only match part of your `@include` statement (see [here](https://regex101.com/r/uC2zO7/1)). A better regex would be `/@include sprite-[^;]*;/g` (see [here](https://regex101.com/r/qC4wY6/1)).

Now you can use [`map-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-stream) to get to the files in your stream and then just use regular JavaScript regex matching to find all occurrences of your pattern and log them to the console:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var map = require('map-stream');

function logMatches(regex) {
  return map(function(file, done) {
    file.contents.toString().match(regex).forEach(function(match) {
      console.log(file.path + ': ' + match);
    });
    done(null, file);
  });
}

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('sass/**/*.sass')
    .pipe(logMatches(/@include sprite-[^;]*;/g));
});
```

Comment: For the regex I'd use a simple ´/@include sprite-.*/g´ as it's more straight-forward.